# every $I\!\trianglelefteq\!R$ is free $\Longleftrightarrow$ $R$ is a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

In a [discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16953/are-submodules-of-free-modules-free) on MO, I found someone claiming the following:

**Proposition:** For a commutative unital ring $R$, the following are equivalent:

(i) every submodule of a free $R$-module is free;
(ii) every ideal $I\!\trianglelefteq\!R$ is free as a $R$-module;
(iii) $R$ is a PID.

*Proof:* (i)$\Rightarrow$(ii) is obvious.

(iii)$\Rightarrow$(i) is theorem 8.6.1 in Grillet's Abstract Algebra.

But how can I prove (ii)$\Rightarrow$(iii)? I have to prove that $xy=0$ implies $x=0$ or $y=0$; and also that every $I\!\trianglelefteq\!R$ is of the form $I=(a)$. We know every $I\!\trianglelefteq\!R$ has a basis $B=\{b_i;i\!\in\!I\}$ and therefore $I\cong R^{(B)}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Re-written, for clarity*

**Lemma 1**: A non-zero free $R$-module is either isomorphic to $R$ or contains a sub-module isomorphic to $R\oplus R$.

**Proof**: Obvious

**Lemma 2**: If $I\!\trianglelefteq\!R$, then $I$ cannot contain a sub-module isomorphic to $R\oplus R$.

**Proof**: If $I$ contains a sub-module isomorphic to $R\oplus R$, then there are $x_1,x_2\in I$ such that $\forall r_1,r_2\in R: r_1x_1 + r_2x_2 = 0$ if and only if $r_1=r_2=0.$  But we can see that $x_2(x_1) + (-x_2)x_1 = 0$, so such $x_1,x_2$ cannot exist.

**Lemma 3**: Given $r\in R$, if $I=(r)$ is isomorphic to $R$, then $r$ is not a zero-divisor of $R$.

**Proof**: Obvious.

**Lemma 4**: If $I\!\trianglelefteq\!R$ is a free $R$-module, then $I$ is principal.

**Proof**: By the lemmas 1 and 2 above, $I$ must be $(0)$ or isomorphic to $R$ as an $R$-module.  But that means $I$ is principal.

**Theorem**: If every ideal of $R$ is a free $R$-module, then $R$ is a PID.

**Proof**: By Lemma 4, every ideal must be principal.  By Lemma 3, $R$ cannot have zero divisors. So $R$ is a PID.

Comment: Aha, this proves the basis has only $1$ element, so every ideal is principal. What about the non-existence of zero divisors?

Comment: If $(r)$ is isomorphic to $R$ as $R$-modules, then $r$ cannot be a zero-divisor.

Comment: Okay, made the "no zero divisors" part more explicit.

Comment: Great, thank you very much :).